# Trying to find the dimensions of a rectangle that would result in the max area

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, quadratics

> Bob has $120m$ of fencing. He is planning on building a rectangular enclosure for his cows. He will build the enclosure alongside his barn and will fence in the remaining **three** sides. Determine the dimensions that will result in the maximum area.

Answer: Max area of $1800m^2$ when the dimensions are $60m$ x $30m$

I started with $$2x+y=120$$
And changed it to $$y=120-2x$$
Which I substituted into the equation for area ($A=xy$) $$A=x(120-2x)$$
I expanded this then completed the square and got $$-2(x-60)^2 +1800$$

Now I'm confused, I thought the vertex would be the two sides, but I got 60, which is one of the answers. I thought maybe I would plug 60 back into the original equation to get the other side but $120-2*60=0$ and zero can't be the other side. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I expanded this then completed the square and got..."  Check all of your work for that step.  Note: $x(120-2x)=-2x^2+120x=-2(x^2-60x)=-2(x^2-60x+\square-\square)$.  Focus solely on what is inside of the parenthesis for now.  I expect you just confused yourself with the $120x$ forgetting that inside of the parenthesis it is a $-60x$ instead.

Comment: As an aside, if you were allowed to use calculus instead of just memorized formula for quadratics and their vertices., you would look at $\frac{d}{dx}[A]=\frac{d}{dx}[-2x^2+120x]=-4x+120$ and set that equal to zero and solve for $x$.  It requires much less algebraic manipulation and arithmetic than the method you used and with enough practice can even be accomplished entirely with mental calculations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here

$$A=x(120-2x)$$

completing the square we obtain

$$A=-2x^2+120x=-2(x-30)^2+1800$$

from which we obtain $x=30$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ has zeros at $0$ and $60$.  Being a quadratic 
polynomial its maximum occurs at $30$.

Answer (score 0):

> I started with $2x+y=120$

Alt. hint:   by AM-GM $\;\displaystyle\sqrt{2x \cdot y} \le \frac{2x+y}{2}=60 \iff x y \le 1800\,$ with equality iff $\,2x =y\,$.

Answer (score 0):

It goes much easier if use of calculus is allowed... derivative

$$ dA/dx= d(120 x -2 x^2)=0 \rightarrow x= 30, y= 60. $$